# elementary OS Juno - desktop vanishes after boot

Tags: desktop

first post so bear with me. Installed elementary OS Juno on a 6y old eMachine using default settings. All went well until the first boot. I can see the desktop and toolbar at the bottom for a second and then it goes blank although I see the top right icons (battery, turn off icon). I can get to the console.
I did some online research and found some bug related infos but no really fitted what is happening to me. I tried to restart the lightdm and other tips but nada :( Thanks for your support of a newbie :)

Answer (score -1):

I run

```
sudo apt update 

sudo apt full-upgrade

reboot
```

and all good.

I hope this will help somebody else :)